# Condense Multiple Variables

Tags: python, datatable, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have tons of variables and argument definitions. Is there a way to make this take up less lines, or am I stuck with it?

```
# Standard input module to absorb commands from CLI
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='User inputs source and destination tables to transfer data.')
parser.add_argument('src_table', help='Source table not supplied.', type=str)
parser.add_argument('dest_table', help='Destination table not supplied.', nargs='?', type=str)  # optional arg
parser.add_argument('instance_object', help='New item not supplied.', nargs='?', type=str)
parser.add_argument('instance_id', help='Item ID not supplied.', nargs='?', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
src_table = args.src_table
dest_table = args.dest_table
```

Comment: You can construct some sort of list or dictionary of parameters, and call `add_argument` in a loop.  `Ipython` gets many of its `argparse` parameters from its `config` files.  I'd be wary of defining too many of the arguments as optional positionals (e.g. `?`).  That can be confusing for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Resist the urge to create tons of variables. Access the values through `args` instead.

However, it is *possible* to convert all the attributes of `args` into global variables:

```
globals().update(**vars(args))
```

but this pollutes the global namespace.
A better option is to pass the `args` to a function:

```
def main(src_table, dest_table, instance_object, instance_id):
    print(src_table, dest_table, instance_object, instance_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='User inputs source and destination tables to transfer data.')
    parser.add_argument('src_table', help='Source table not supplied.', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('dest_table', help='Destination table not supplied.', nargs='?', type=str)  # optional arg
    parser.add_argument('instance_object', help='New item not supplied.', nargs='?', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('instance_id', help='Item ID not supplied.', nargs='?', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(**vars(args))
```

Thus, inside of `main`, all of `arg`'s attributes will be accessible as local variables. Structuring your program this way allows your code to be used as both a script and be importable as a module. This makes your code more versatile, and is thus much nicer than "polluting" the global namespace with lots of variables.